# Pyramid config loading error

Tags: python, configuration, pyramid

I've got an issue with creating an app in Pyramid. When I try to serve through paster, I get:

```
  File "/home/viraptor/blah/blah/__init__.py", line 23, in main
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
  File "/home/viraptor/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid/config.py", line 916, in make_wsgi_app
    self.commit()
  File "/home/viraptor/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid/config.py", line 491, in commit
    self._ctx.execute_actions()
  File "/home/viraptor/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/zope/configuration/config.py", line 626, in execute_actions
    callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/viraptor/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid/config.py", line 1291, in register
    derived_view = deriver(view)
  File "/home/viraptor/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid/config.py", line 2681, in __call__
    self.mapped_view(view))))))))
  File "/home/viraptor/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid/config.py", line 2624, in inner
    wrapped_view = wrapped(self, view)
  File "/home/viraptor/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid/config.py", line 2693, in mapped_view
    mapped_view = mapper(**self.kw)(view)
  File "/home/viraptor/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid/config.py", line 2860, in __call__
    view = self.map_nonclass(view)
  File "/home/viraptor/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid/config.py", line 2876, in map_nonclass
    ronly = requestonly(view, self.attr)
  File "/home/viraptor/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid/config.py", line 2966, in requestonly
    if len(args) - len(defaults) == 1:
zope.configuration.config.ConfigurationExecutionError: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
  in:
  ('/home/viraptor/blah/blah/__init__.py', 22, 'main', "config.add_route('customer', '/customer/{customer_id}', view='blah.views.customer.view', view_renderer='customer_view.mak', view_permission='view', traverse='/customer/{customer_id}')")
```

What can be the reason for this? I haven't even changed that configuration lately, only the rest of the app.

Comment: You didn't include the actual exception, only the stacktrace. Noone knows what happened now, only where… :-)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - Python prints the exception at the end - it's there. It was ConfigurationExecutionError.

Comment: Ah, my fault, the mobile view on my iPhone didn't show the whole text and I had no indication that it was longer. Apologies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you hit a bug fixed in newer revisions of Pyramid; your traceback indicates that either `args` or `defaults` is `None`, but that code branch cannot be reached unless `args` is not `None`, leaving the possibility that `defaults` is `None` instead. I found the following commit to Pyramids that adds a specific test for `defaults` being None:

https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/commit/f168197609169fb01b65adeb3eb59d069000fe2c

I say you have a method without any defaults and only a request parameter (`method(self, request)`, the work-around would be to add a keyword argument with a default (`method(self, request, dummy=None)`.

Disclaimer: haven't yet had a chance to work with Pyramid, so my analysis is based purely on the Pyramid codebase.

Answer (score 0):

`config.add_route` accepts only 1 positional argument, your second argument should be use keyworded with `pattern`.

Secondly, I don't think is possible to have the same pattern for `route` and the `traverse`. With the `traverse` keyword you are definining where the `root` should start. It's explained in the [`Configurator` API documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_route).

The error exception raised could more informative though.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to have similar traverse= as pattern= arguments in URL Dispatch when using the tree in a hybrid approach. Also, while the pattern is a keyword argument in add_route, basically all of the documentation treats it as a positional argument.